# Chart - Automatic highlighting Zero Points

Tags: c#, graph

So basically I have a graph as below in the image, I am going to be implementing some check boxes to enable and disable each line graph. 
My main question is:

As you can see on the graphs there is dips in the data down to ZERO - How do I get these to automatically highlight for the user to see!

I.e. Set a point on the X Axis that displays interval!

[image]

Comment: What are you using to draw the graph?

Comment: It is obviously a Chart control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to add a  another `Series` of `ChartType Point` and add only those Zero `Points` as red dots..:

[image]

```
    // add a new Series:
    Series sz = chart1.Series.Add("Zeroes");
    sz.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;
    sz.Color = Color.Red;
    sz.BorderWidth = 3;


    // add Points wherever the other series is zero or less
    foreach (DataPoint dp in chart1.Series[0].Points )
    {
        if (dp.YValues[0] <= 0) sz.Points.AddXY(dp.XValue, 0);
    }
```

If you need to check on more `Series` you can repeat the loop for them..

Comment: Thanks, great idea. I have another question but will post it.

Comment: Just quickly to add, I actually didn't get this to work using the method above? Because I am setting my series in the actual designer. Tried this way and doesnt work.

Comment: Well you need to access the right series, either by index or by their names, which you can also use as indexers. - So, is it working for you now?

Comment: I have set it to the correct series (I think).. And it creates the series.. But the points are not highlighted.

Comment: Do you mean that there are no Points added? You should use the debugger to a) look at the Points in the data series: Are realy no YValues <= 0? (Maybe they are just very small but still <0??? and b) set a brakpont on the `sz.Points.AddXY(dp.XValue, 0);` call: does it really never get called..